# Azure AD and Windows 10 and username

Tags: integration, windows-10, azure-active-directory

I have hooked up my Windows 10 machine to Azure AD, which worked quite smoothly. However, the username it created locally is AzureAD\FirstnameLastname. Since I have an umlaut in my last name, it even used this for my username, which will call out for troubles sooner or later.

Is there any way in which I can influence the username it creates locally? Ideally I would also like to use our company realm rather than the generic AzureAD and choose a more appropriate username.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: What is your goal with Azure AD? Is it to join your computer to your company domain?

Comment: yes; i'd like to get rid of the on premise ad and replace it with azure ad...

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I just ran into this almost 3 years later: https://serverfault.com/questions/925928/how-can-i-configure-the-sam-account-name-in-the-azuread-that-i-got-with-office-3

Comment: Not really, azure ad is not powerful enough to replace normal ad. We keep your a federated setup and join the computers to the proper domain rather than aad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a different account that you use to log in at your workplace that's different from your personal Microsoft account. If your computer is domain joined, you can log in using that work based email, and it should set up your username in the company realm. If your workplace has, for example, an Office 365 account, use whatever email you log into that with to set up your Azure AD at home.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/05/28/azure-ad-join-on-windows-10-devices.aspx

If your company isn't already using Azure AD/Office 365 then this method won't work - they'll have to be set up on their end too. If this is about getting the company itself on Azure AD, start with the documentation about setup and go from there https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-new-forest-virtual-machine/  From within the Azure Portal for your Azure AD you can add and edit users.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Amanda. We are actually using Office 365 including Azure AD for it, and I did connect my computer using the method described in the first link. However, doing this yields the realm AzureAD and there is no way to influence it. 

It is an interesting idea to open a proper AD Forrest within Azure. I was actually hoping to get rid of the proper AD completely, but it seems to be the only way to control user names and realm. Unfortunately, we will also need the Azure AD for Office 365 and Visual Studio online. I guess this means that we will also have to set up a server as ADFS?

Comment: Sorry for slow response, but that should fix it, good luck and let me know how it goes!